# Open source software for noise modelling (GIS) as an alternative to Soundplan

Tags: open-source, audio, modeling

Is there an alternative open source software that performs as noise modelling tool compared to [Soundplan](https://www.soundplan.eu/) (Proprietary)? QGIS has a plugin “Openoise” but doesn’t function as compared to Soundplan

Answer (score 2):

This is a *highly specialized* work field, with really complex software. As a GIS specialist, I have worked with a company that specialized in this type of 3D sound modeling software in (urban) spaces developing tools for our national government. I must admit that it is a long time ago, but I doubt this is the type of setting "open source software" thrives. It requires huge investments with only a limited amount of clients, and there is a strong legal framework (both national and e.g. EU) for this, and tools must adhere to these and be (technically) verified.

Unless there is some research group in a university that releases an open source alternative, finding one "on par" with commercial software, seems unlikely to me.

Then again, as I wrote, it is quite some time I was involved in this, so don't know the current situation for sure.

Comment: This sound more like a comment rather than a recommendation.

Comment: Yes, but I figured it might be useful to the OP, as there is probably not a lot of people out here capable of giving any guidance. As I wrote, this is a highly specialized field. That doesn't necessarily mean there can't be good Open Source software out there, but from my personal experience, this may not be so likely. Before the OP spends days in vain searching, or waiting on an answer that may never materialize (but of course I would like to be wrong here), he / she might like to be aware of this. And yes, I probably should have posted it as a comment rather than "answer". Alas...